# Trying to get MYSQL variables to print for my highscores

Tags: php, mysql, variables

here's the script im having issues with..
I'm making an in-game Kills high-score board for my game, and I'm trying to make this mysql query work but i can't get it.

Can anyone please help me.

```
if($i < $top_hiscore && !in_array($row["playerName"], $banned) && !in_array(ucwords($row["playerName"]), $banned)) {
  if($i & 1) {
    echo '<tr class="row row1">
          <td class="rankCol">'.$i.'</td>ITS HERE
          <td class="alL"><a href="'.$website.'/'.$pers.'?name='.$row["playerName"].'" target="_self">'.BBCode($row["playerName"]).'</a></td>
          <td class="alL">'.getKillsFor('.$row["playerName"].').'</td>
          </tr>';
  } else {
    echo '<tr class="row row2">
          <td class="rankCol">'.$i.'</td>
          <td class="alL"><a href="'.$website.'/'.$pers.'?name='.$row["playerName"].'" target="_self">'.BBCode($row["playerName"]).'</a></td>
          <td class="alL">'.getKillsFor('.$row["playerName"].').'</td>
          </tr>';
  }
}
```

and here's the getkillsfor method... Which is what is incorrect

```
function getKillsFor($name) { 
  $kquery = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM skills WHERE playerName ='".$name."'") or die(mysql_error());
  $query = mysql_query($kquery);
  $row = mysql_fetch_row($query); 
  $shoeRating = $row[0];
  return $shoeRating[$name]; 
}
```

Comment: what is the purpose of 1 in "if($i & 1)"?

Comment: What do you mean by _incorrect_?  Incorrect result or an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so you know, mysql_query is deprecated. Use PDO and prepared statements instead. Avoid sql injection with people setting $name to be '; or 1=1; # )

The output of mysql_query is a resource, that's the thing that you should send to mysql_fetch_row

So this

```
$kquery = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM skills WHERE playerName ='".$name."'") or die(mysql_error());
$query = mysql_query($kquery);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($query);
```

should be

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM skills WHERE playerName ='".$name."'") or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
```